# Xsens error comunicating with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, xsens

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to run:

$ rosrun xsens_driver mtnode.py

it shows this message:

[WARN] [WallTime: 1362075228.016104] Cannot find value for parameter: ~device, assigning default: auto

[WARN] [WallTime: 1362075228.017062] Cannot find value for parameter: ~baudrate, assigning default: 0

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1362075228.018932] Fatal: could not find proper MT device.

I don't know what is the cause of this error, the only thing I know is that when I plug sensor in the computer it doesn't create the virtual port ttyUSB0, what probably cause the node to doesn't find the sensor and send this error message. Someone know how can I fix this, what is causing this error, something is missing?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Kernel 3.2.0-38-generic-pae, ros fuerte.

**Before** plug in the device:

```
dmesg|grep -i tty
```

[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled

[    1.268379] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[    1.648533] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[   16.461250] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized

**After plug in**

[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled

[    1.268379] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[    1.648533] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[   16.461250] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized

(It's the same answer)

---

```
lsusb
```

**Before plug in**

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. Dell QuietKey Keyboard

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse

**After plug in**

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. Dell QuietKey Keyboard

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse

Bus 005 Device 005: ID 2639:0013

---

And

```
udevadm monitor
```

When I plug in the device:

KERNEL[7687.265214] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2 (usb)

UDEV  [7687.266865] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2 (usb)

KERNEL[7687.268106] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0 (usb)

KERNEL[7687.268202] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.1 (usb)

UDEV  [7687.269808] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.1 (usb)

UDEV  [7687.270150] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0 (usb)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56635/xsens-error-comunicating-with-ubuntu-12.04/) by [Gabrielcarioca](https://answers.ros.org/users/4321/gabrielcarioca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-28**:
Please add `dmesg` output when you plug in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are aware of this issue when using 4th generation MTi's (orange-coloured PCB/aluminum casing).

Currently, we are working on a new release of the Software Suite that solves these kind of connectivity issues when using the Xsens USB driver in Linux. Serial (RS232) interfaces don't experience this issue.

Marcel, Xsens

---

Originally posted by [marcel_xsens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4344/marcel_xsens/) with karma: 26 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-04**:
Do the new ones have a custom USB interface (i.e no more FTDI) or is the problem just a custom vendor/product id for the FTDI?

**Comment by [marcel_xsens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4344/marcel_xsens/) on 2013-03-04**:
It is indeed a new USB interface, that comes directly from the PCB. It uses WinUSB. There is a driver for Linux in Gihub, but it may not work directly out of the box: https://github.com/xsens/xsens_mt

**Comment by [Gabrielcarioca](https://answers.ros.org/users/4321/gabrielcarioca/) on 2013-03-05**:
There is a prevision for when this new Software Suite will come out? Where can I obtain a cable with serial interface RS232 for this MTi generation?

**Comment by [Mark Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10231/mark-chen/) on 2013-12-28**:
Hi, Marcel. I have the the same problem. When the MTi-700 is inserted into the USB cable, no /dev/ttyUSB0 is created. However, when I inserted another USB-RS232 device, the /dev/ttyUSB0 file was successfully created. Do you have any idea about this?

**Comment by [Mark Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10231/mark-chen/) on 2013-12-29**:
I have solved this problem. The ttyUSB0 is concerned about the Linux version. My previous version is Ubuntu 12.04 3.2.0, and was then updated to 3.8.0. Now it works. It seems that the problem is due to the lack of the module ehci-pci.

After updating the kernel, the following two steps should be run:

1. sudo modprobe usbserial
2. sudo insmod /home/abhishek/xsens_driver/xsens_mt/xsens_mt.ko (the xsens_mt.ko can be obtained by make the drive on http://github.com/xsens/xsens_mt).

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2014-04-30**:
Hi, I also use an xsens MTI-G 700 on ubuntu 12.04. I use the xsens_driver from the hydro debs and have the problem, that the configuration call "rosrun xsens_driver mtdevice.py --configure --output-mode=coapvs --output-settings=tqMAG" causes both the mtdevice.py as well as the node to fail have parsing problems: "MT error: could not parse MTData message" does anybody have an idea? both work fine when I use: rosrun xsens_driver "mtdevice.py -c -s 0x1 -m 0x4"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having same error. Writting the following command (before executing the node):

`sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0`

to give permission for the port worked for me. Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [miguel_sgp](https://answers.ros.org/users/7061/miguel_sgp/) with karma: 26 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

same error was coming in my system and it was solved by following procedure.

Install linux driver if your kernel version is less than 3.9

The hardware driver of the USB interface for Linux can be found on http://github.com/xsens/xsens_mt.

make the driver, and install it using the following commands

1. make
2. sudo modprobe usbserial
3. sudo insmod /home/abhishek/xsens_driver/xsens_mt/xsens_mt.ko

---

Originally posted by [AbhishekMehta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2140/abhishekmehta/) with karma: 226 on 2013-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10231/mark-chen/) on 2013-12-25**:
Thanks, AbhishekMehta. However, this solution doesn't work for me. The Ubuntu 12.04 still can't find the IMU (Xsens MTI-G 700). Do you have any idea about this error? (The system can identify the USB insertion, but can't find the /dev/ttyUSB0)

**Comment by [AbhishekMehta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2140/abhishekmehta/) on 2013-12-26**:
after connecting Xsens via USB, run 2nd and 3rd command. I have to do that every time the system boots.

**Comment by [Mark Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10231/mark-chen/) on 2013-12-28**:
Thank you, AbhishekMehta. I have solved this problem.

**Comment by [vinmean](https://answers.ros.org/users/27224/vinmean/) on 2016-12-12**:
Is there a similar solution for 3.10.96 kernel? I get error when executing make command. I am trying to interface xsens MTi-300 IMU with Nvidia TX1 (has the above kernel version). lsusb identifies the xsens sensor but /dev/ttyUSB0 is not created.

**Comment by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on 2017-02-27**:
@vinmean The steps in this post fixed the make error for me:

https://base.xsens.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/211806629-MTi-300-not-working-on-NVIDIA-TX1-platform-Kernel-3-10-96-

I also needed to run `sudo depmod` after the other steps for the module to be loaded at boot.